# Declaring defined property of a third party library

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So i'm using a React UI library called Evergreen, which isn't typed.

I was writing out a declaration for the components i'm using, when I hit a bit of a snag, the Menu is structured in React as such:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Group>
        <Menu.Item>Share...</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item>Move...</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item>Rename...</Menu.Item>
    </Menu.Group>
    <Menu.Divider />
    <Menu.Group>
        <Menu.Item intent="danger">Delete...</Menu.Item>
    </Menu.Group>
</Menu>
```

But `Menu.Group`, `Menu.Item` and `Menu,Divider` are throwing errors saying `Property 'Divider' does not exist on type 'typeof Menu'`

Currently the declaration for the menu is as follows:

```js
export interface IMenuProps extends ICSSProps {
    is?: any;
    onSelect?: any;
    icon?: any;
    children?: any;
    secondaryText?: any;
    appearance?: string;
    intent?: any;
    theme?: any;    
}
export class Menu extends React.PureComponent<IMenuProps> {}
```

I'm fairly new to TS, so have absolutely no idea how to declare these, I've tried adding something like `Divider: () => void;` to IMenuProps, and i've tried adding `public Divider: any;` to the menu class, but no luck (not that I'm surprised)!

I'd really appreciate it if anyone can even point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The dot notation components need to be defined inside the class as stateless functional components and pass the interface in via that! Here's a snippet in case anyone need it.

```js
export class Menu extends React.PureComponent<IMenuProps> {

        public static Group: React.SFC<IMenuGroup>;
        public static Divider: React.SFC<IMenuDivider>;
        public static Item: React.SFC<IMenuItem>;

    }

    export interface IMenuGroup extends ICSSProps {
        title: string;
        group: string;
    }

    export interface IMenuDivider extends ICSSProps {
        title: string;
        divider: string;
    }

    export interface IMenuItem extends ICSSProps {
        title: string;
        item: string;
    }
}
```